# Gift certificate system

Tags: java, oop, object

Here's my problem: 
write a program to ask the winner to choose from the following list of items. each time they pick an item, display the remaining balance and the total amount. if there is no available item left, the remaining balance can be converted to cash. display all the list of items that was purchased.

I have a hard time to get the "each time they pick an item, display the remaining balance and the total amount. if there is no available item left, the remaining balance can be converted to cash. display all the list of items that was purchased. " problem

Here's my code:

```
public void ShowTotalA(){
        double price =0.0, total =0.0;

        if(item==1){
            price = 20000;
        }else if(item==2){
            price = 5000;
        }else if(item==3){
            price = 8000;
        }else if(item==4){
            price = 10000;
        }else if(item==5){
            price = 9000;
        }else if(item==6){
            price = 15000;
        }else if(item==7){
            price = 10000;
        }else if(item==8){
            price = 18000;
        }else if(item==9){
            price = 11000;
        }else if(item==10){
            price = 17000;
        }
        for(int i =5000; i <boxA;i++){

           total = price*qnt;
           boxA = boxA-total;



        System.out.println("Total Amount is: " + total);
        System.out.println("Remaining balance is: " + boxA + "\n");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------\n");
        }
        }


    public void ShowTotalB(){
        double price =0.0, total =0.0, balance =0.0;
        if(item==1){
            price = 10000;
        }else if(item==2){
            price = 9000;
        }else if(item==3){
            price = 5000;
        }else if(item==4){
            price = 8000;
        }else if(item==5){
            price = 5500;
        }else if(item==6){
            price = 6000;
        }else if(item==7){
            price = 9000;
        }else if(item==8){
            price = 6000;
        }else if(item==9){
            price = 7000;
        }else if(item==10){
            price = 9000;
        }
        total = price*qnt;
        balance = boxB-total;

        System.out.println("Total Amount is: " + total);
        System.out.println("Remaining balance is: " + balance);


        }

}
```

Comment: You forgot the code.

Comment: First step: get out a piece of paper and a pencil, and walk through doing the math on the paper for the transactions.  That should help you figure out your program flow.